# Pagination / mysql query failing

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

This is a strange one, i have ammended my mysql queries to show only results **"WHERE `domain_available`='Y' AND `domain_category`!='N/A' AND `domain_crawler_id`='0'"** when i manually go in to PHPMyAdmin and do an sql query test it brings back the proper results (**57**) but when i run the script the rows count: **echo $total_results;** brings back all 1300+ results, even though i manually test in the phpmyadmin query table, it brings back the results perfectly.

```
<?php

include('includes/sessions.php');
include('includes/db_connection.php');
include('includes/functions.php');
include('includes/header.php');
include('includes/navbar-logged.php');

?>

<?php

$crawlId = isset($_GET['urlId']) ? $_GET['urlId'] : '';

?>

<?php

if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page    = 1;
} else {
    $page    = $_GET['page'];
}

$userInfo    = get_logged_in_users_details($member);
$canEdit     = false;

if ($userInfo['user_class'] === 'Site Administrator') {
    $canEdit = true;
}

$sort        = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'domain_id';
$max_results = 500;
$from        = ($page * $max_results) - $max_results;

if (isset($crawlId)) {

    $rows = DB::getInstance()->select("
        SELECT  *
        FROM    `domains`
        WHERE   `domain_available`='Y' AND `domain_crawler_id`='{$crawlId}'
        ORDER   BY `{$sort}` DESC
        LIMIT   :from, :max_results",
    [
        'from' => [
            'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT,
            'value' => $from
        ],
        'max_results' => [
            'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT,
            'value' => $max_results
        ]
    ]);

} else {

    $rows = DB::getInstance()->select("
        SELECT  *
        FROM    `domains`
        WHERE   `domain_available`='Y' AND `domain_category`!='N/A' AND `domain_crawler_id`='0'
        ORDER   BY `{$sort}` DESC
        LIMIT   :from, :max_results",
    [
        'from' => [
            'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT,
            'value' => $from
        ],
        'max_results' => [
            'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT,
            'value' => $max_results
        ]
    ]);

}

if (isset($crawlId)) {
     $total_results = DB::getInstance()->selectValue("SELECT count(*) FROM `domains` WHERE`domain_crawler_id`='{$crawlId}'");   
} else {
     $total_results = DB::getInstance()->selectValue("SELECT count(*) FROM `domains` WHERE `domain_available`='Y' AND `domain_category`!='N/A' AND `domain_crawler_id`='0'");
}

echo $total_results;

if (count($rows) < 1) {
    stderr('Sorry, <b>no</b> domains to show you yet!');
}

$backLinksData = getBackLinksByDomains($rows);
$isPremiumUser = (int)$user['paid_fees'] === 1;

?>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Search for expired domains quickly.</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form action="results.php" method="get" class="form-horizontal container-fluid" role="form">

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="" class="control-label">Domain Contains:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" name="keywords" class="form-control" size="40" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label for="" class="control-label">Anchor Contains:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" name="anchor" class="form-control" size="40" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label class="control-label">DA:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="da" value="0" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label class="control-label">PA:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="pa" value="0" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label class="control-label">TF:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="tf" value="0" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label class="control-label">CF:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="cf" value="0" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label class="control-label">Domains Born After:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="number" min="1990" max="2016" name="age" value="1999" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <label class="control-label" style="display: inline-block;">&nbsp;</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Search for domains using <b>your</b> criteria.</div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Browse Domains - <b>*<font color="orange">spam</font>*</b> = Potential spam domain! <b>*<font color="red">HP</font>*</b> = A homepage link points to this domain!</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Alexa</th>
                    <th>Domain / Category</th>
                    <th><a href="expired-domains.php?sort=domain_moz_da">DA</a></th>
                    <th><a href="expired-domains.php?sort=domain_moz_pa">PA</a></th>
                    <th><a href="expired-domains.php?sort=domain_tf">TF</a></th>
                    <th><a href="expired-domains.php?sort=domain_cf">CF</a></th>
                    <th><a href="expired-domains.php?sort=domain_indexed">Indexed</a></th>
                    <th><a href="expired-domains.php?sort=domain_age">Age</a></th>
                    <th>BL</th>
                    <th><a href="expired-domains.php?sort=domain_ref_domains">RD</a></th>
                    <th>Found</th>
                    <?php if ($canEdit): ?>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
                    <?php
                        //$bgcolor = ($bgcolor == '#eeeeee'? '#ffffff': '#eeeeee');
                        $domID     = $row['domain_id'];
                        $domNM     = $row['domain_name'];
                        $domDT     = $row['domain_date'];
                        $domAL     = $row['domain_alexa_rank']; 
                        $domDA     = $row['domain_moz_da']; 
                        $domPA     = $row['domain_moz_pa']; 
                        $domTF     = $row['domain_tf']; 
                        $domCF     = $row['domain_cf']; 
                        $domRD     = $row['domain_ref_domains']; 
                        $domDC     = $row['domain_age']; 
                        $domIN     = $row['domain_indexed']; 
                        $domHP     = $row['domain_homepage']; 
                        $domCT     = $row['domain_category']; 

                        $time_1    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($domDT . ' +1 hour'));
                        $time_2    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

                        $string    = $domNM;
                        $array     = array("sunglasses","payday","casino","viagra","cashloans","loans","sex","porn","xxx");
                        $spam      = 0;

                        foreach ($array as $token) {
                            if (stristr($string, $token) !== FALSE) {
                                $spam = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($domAL); ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            $domainUrl = $isPremiumUser ? $domNM : getObscuredUrl($domNM);
                            $domainCat = ($domCT == "N/A") ? "<font color=\"red\"><b>Uncategorized</b></font>" : "<font color=\"green\"><b>{$domCT}</b></font>";
                            ?>
                            <a href="domain-details.php?id=<?php echo $domID; ?>"><b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($domainUrl); ?></b></a> <b>in</b> <?php echo $domainCat; ?>
                            <?php if ($time_2 <= $time_1) { ?>
                                <b>(<font color="red">NEW</font>)</b>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if ($spam) { ?>
                                <b>*<font color="orange">spam</font>*</b>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php if ($domHP) { ?>
                                <b>*<font color="red">HP</font>*</b>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <?php echo $domDA; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <?php echo $domPA; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <?php echo $domTF; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <?php echo $domCF; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        G=<?php if ($domIN == 0) { echo "<font color=\"red\"><b>No</b></font>"; } else { echo "<font color=\"green\"><b>Yes</b></font>"; } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <?php if ($domDC == "????") { echo "<b><font color=\"red\">????</font></b>"; } else { echo $domDC; } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <?= isset($backLinksData[$domNM]) ? $backLinksData[$domNM] : 0; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <?php if (empty($domRD)) { echo "-"; } else { echo $domRD; } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <b><?php echo date("m.d.y", strtotime($domDT)); ?></b>
                        </td>
                        <?php if ($canEdit): ?>
                            <td>(<a href="master-edit-domain.php?id=<?php echo $domID ?>">e</a>)-(<a href="master-delete-domain.php?id=<?php echo $domID ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this domain?');">d</a>)</td>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
        <?php pagination($page, $total_results, $max_results) ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php

include('includes/footer.php');
```

I cannot see why the query works in phpmyadmin, but fails when i run the script, is there something i have overlooked, and help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe because `$crawlID` is _always_ set??

Comment: just add a `echo isset($crawlId);` after `$crawlId = isset($_GET['urlId'])....` and check it out yourself.

Comment: you maybe want to use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead of isset

Answer (score 2):

`$crawlId` is *always* set here, because you set it at the very top. You set it to '' though, which will still count as *set*.

So you might wanna use `if(!empty($crawlId)) {...}` instead of `isset()`